# Drag Drop copy file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, forms

I've perhaps done something marginally stupid, but can't see what it is!!

```
string pegasusKey = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Pegasus\";
        string opera2ServerPath = @"Server VFP\";
        string opera3ServerPath = @"O3 Client VFP\";
        string opera2InstallationPath = null;
        string opera3InstallationPath = null;

        //Gets the opera Installtion paths and reads to the string opera*InstallationPath
        opera2InstallationPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(pegasusKey + opera2ServerPath +    "System", "PathToServerDynamic", null);
        opera3InstallationPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(pegasusKey + opera3ServerPath + "System", "PathToServerDynamic", null);

        string Filesource = null;
        string[] FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
        foreach (string File in FileList)
            Filesource = File;
        label.Text = Filesource;

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(opera3InstallationPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Copy(Filesource, opera3InstallationPath);
            MessageBox.Show("File Copied from" + Filesource + "\n to" + opera3InstallationPath);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Directory Doesn't Exist");
        }
```

The user drags the file onto the window, I then get the installation path of an application which is then used as the destination for the source file.. When the application is runs, it throws the error directory not found. But surely if the directory doesn't exists is should step into the else statement? a simple application that is becoming a headache!!

Comment: Does it actually hit the if statement?

Comment: Yes, it goes through the if statement.. and i know the directory exists
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhro4yox0wjc63o/vs.PNG

Comment: It's an application directory, i can't see how it wouldn't exist from the time of checking?.. To writing. Could it possibly be folder permissions which stop the application writing to it, therefore throwing the exception. Although, i would have though it would have been a different error if it was to do with security issues on the folder

Comment: I also assume wherever Filesource references, also exists?

Comment: When the user drags and drops the file onto the form the string filesource is updated with the file location. so filesource essentially becomes, for instance
c:/user/desktop/helloworld.txt

Comment: Could this by any chance be related to file system virtualization..?

Comment: If it was, is there anyway i could overcome it? Even if i hard code the source path and destination path in as System.IO.File.Copy(@"C\helloworld.text", @"C\Users\Desktop, true);
it still errors with an exception

Comment: The 2nd parameter to File.Copy() must be a file path, not a directory path.

Comment: Ahh!! meaning the name of the file.. Must it be in the same directory as the source then? Or does the directory come first and then the file name? File.Copy(sourceLocation, file name, true);

Comment: First parameter is full path to source file, second parameter is full path to destination file.

Answer (score 0):

Your Filesource must be invalid. Here's what I suggest:

1. Step your code, put a break point on first line of the if(Directory.Exists(...)) code block.
2. Examine Filesource by adding it to the watch window, check if it is what you expect
3. Open the "Immediate Window"  Type File.Exists(Filesource) and check result (should be true). Or.. Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectory(Filesource))

Also, I'm almost certain you have a logic error in this portion of your code.. (You are assigning a variable in a loop over and over again, did you mean to append it? This doesn't make sense).

```
    string Filesource = null;
    string[] FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    foreach (string File in FileList)
        Filesource = File;
    label.Text = Filesource;
```